# Проверка на целое число

Tags: python

На ввод дается два чилса в одной строчке через пробел, Нужно проверить целые они или нет, если нет, то вывести:"Неправильный формат ввода". Вот мой код:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())

if int(a)/float(a)==1.0:
    print('является целым числом')
else:
    print('не целое число.')

if int(b)/float(b)==1.0:
    print('является целым числом')
else:
    print('не целое число.')
```

Comment: И что с твоим кодом?

Comment: float(a) - int(a) == 0

Comment: @Anton Nikolaev, `2.0` и `2`?

Comment: @Zhihar 2.0 это с точки зрения математики не целое?

Comment: а это целое или с правающей запятой в рамках python?

Comment: @Эникейщик если ввожу нецелое число, выдаёт ошибку. Навреное потому что стоит int(input())

Comment: А не нужно гадать. Нужно читать текст ошибки, тогда не будет этих "наверное"

Comment: Ну и я настоятельно рекомендую посмотреть на последовательность  манипуляций с введеными данными...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут двоякая ситуация

1. если надо проверить, что некоторое число является целым, то можно сделать так:

   ```
    value = 2.0

    print(float(value) == int(value))
   ```
2. если же надо определить, что ввели именно целое число или число с плавающей запятой, то можно сделать более хитро:

   ```
    text = "2.0"

    exec(f"value = {text}")

    print(isinstance(value, float))
   ```

Comment: мне нужен второй вариант, но value подчёркивается красным, значит нет этой переменной? exec(f"value = {text}"), с этой строчкой помоему что-то не так

Comment: это редактор думает что ее нет, но после выполнения `exec` она будет, так что никакой ошибки не произойдет

Comment: а как вместо первой строки, сделать a, b = map(int, input().split()), чтоб всё работало, а так галочку я поставил)

Comment: вам надо просто строку разбить на слова и дальше пройти в цикле и собрать строку `value = {строка из списка}` и выполнить проверку которую я написал

Comment: `(3.2).is_integer()`

Comment: `exec` - это слишком хитро. Всегда слишком хитро.

Comment: да, возможно микроскопом вбил гвоздь, но решение же имеет право на жизнь?

Comment: Вызов `exec` разрешён агентам с лицензией на убийство. Вставлять такой совет в ответ на вопрос начинающего не гуманно.

Answer (score 2):

Не такая простая задача если решать её полностью. Есть три с половиной варианта:

1. целое число (0, -33, 16, 1_000_000)
2. - вещественное число (0.1, -123.4, 12e-1, 12.345e2).
   - вещественное число c целым значением (1.0, -16.0, 12.34e2)
3. непонятно что (123s, abracadabra, 1O0).

Целое число распознает `int(s)`. Если `s` строка с целым числом внутри, то вернётся его значение, иначе будет выброшено исключение `ValueError`.

Вещественное число распознает `float(s)`. И тоже выбросит исключение в случае неправильного формата.

Для проверки целочисленного значения вещественного числа пригодится метод `is_integer`.

В третий пункт попадает всё что вообще не выглядит как число.

Проверка на целое число должна идти до проверки на вещественное, иначе все целые числа будут записаны в вещественные.

```
def as_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def as_float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def main():
    s = input()
    i = as_int(s)
    if i is not None:
        print('int', repr(s), i)
        return

    f = as_float(s)
    if f is not None:
        print('float', repr(s), f)
        if f.is_integer():
            print('... of integer value')
        return

    print('???', repr(s))


main()
```

Тест:

```
$ python is_integer.py
1_000_000
int '1_000_000' 1000000

$ python is_integer.py
0
int '0' 0

$ python is_integer.py
-33
int '-33' -33

$ python is_integer.py
16
int '16' 16

$ python is_integer.py
0.1
float '0.1' 0.1

$ python is_integer.py
-123.4
float '-123.4' -123.4

$ python is_integer.py
12e-1
float '12e-1' 1.2

$ python is_integer.py
12.345e2
float '12.345e2' 1234.5

$ python is_integer.py
1.0
float '1.0' 1.0
... of integer value

$ python is_integer.py
-16.0
float '-16.0' -16.0
... of integer value

$ python is_integer.py
12.34e2
float '12.34e2' 1234.0
... of integer value

$ python is_integer.py
123s
??? '123s'

$ python is_integer.py
abracadabra
??? 'abracadabra'

$ python is_integer.py
1O0
??? '1O0'
```

Comment: А как так получается, что ``int(5.34)`` нормально работает, но в ``as_int(s)`` попадает в исключение? Ведь return int(s) должно тогда выдавать 5?

Comment: Сравните `int(5.34)` и `int('5.34')`. Первое - приведение в стиле C (округление специального вида). Второе - чтение значения из строки с проверкой формата.

Comment: ай, ну точно, там же строка 